Multiple combo boxes to one column
is it possible to have multiple combo boxes where values will be place into one column simultaneously? All of the combo boxes under the data item will be in column B of a worksheet and all of the combo boxes under Schedule will be in column C. The value of the textbox at the top will be in column A.


Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim sh As Worksheet, msg As String, arr, c As Range, id
    
    'check for any empty required fields
    If Len(TextBox1.Value) = 0 Then msg = msg & vbLf & " - ID"

    If Len(msg) > 0 Then 'anything missing?
        MsgBox "The following fields are required:" & msg, _
                vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Missing Information"
    Else
        'OK to write to sheet
        Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Employee File")
        Set c = sh.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1) '##start adding here
        arr = Split(TextBox1.Value, ",") '##split on comma to get an array
        For Each id In arr               '##loop over the array
            c.Resize(1, 3).Value = Array(Trim(id), ComboBox1.Value, ComboBox2.Value)
            Set c = c.Offset(1)          '##next output row
        Next id

        MsgBox "Information Added", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Notification"
        Unload Me
    End If
End Sub


Untested but you can loop over the comboboxes, assuming they're all named consecutively (ie. ComboBox1 to ComboBox16):
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim sh As Worksheet, msg As String, arr, c As Range, id, dataItem, schedule, i As Long
    
    'check for any empty required fields
    If Len(TextBox1.Value) = 0 Then msg = msg & vbLf & " - ID"

    If Len(msg) > 0 Then 'anything missing?
        MsgBox "The following fields are required:" & msg, _
                vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Missing Information"
    Else
        'OK to write to sheet
        Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Employee File")
        Set c = sh.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1) 'start adding here
        arr = Split(TextBox1.Value, ",")                      'split on comma to get an array
        
        For i = 1 To 16 Step 2                           '## loop over comboboxes
            dataItem = Me.Controls("ComboBox" & i).Value '## read combo values...
            schedule = Me.Controls("ComboBox" & (i + 1)).Value
            If Len(dataItem) > 0 Then             '## any value selected?
                For Each id In arr                'loop over the id array
                    c.Resize(1, 3).Value = Array(Trim(id), dataItem, schedule)
                    Set c = c.Offset(1)           'next output row
                Next id
            End If
        Next i
        
        MsgBox "Information Added", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Notification"
        Unload Me
    End If
End Sub

